# Replace one category of a categorical variable based on other categorical variable

Tags: python, pandas, replace

I want to know how to replace one category of a variable with some values based on another categorical variable.

I am working with a dataset. It has 2 columns among many. One is x = ['0','1','2','3+'] and the other one is - Propert_Area = ['Urban','Semiurban','Rural'].

I want to replace '3+' with values '3','4'and '5' based on the fact where the property area is. So if property_area is 'Urban', '3+' should be replaced by '3',if property_area is 'Semiurban', '3+' should be replaced by '4' and so on.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do it will be

```
# df is the dataframe 
# x and prop_area are columns 

# iterate over the column
for index, row in df.iterrows():
   if ( df.at[index,'prop_area'] =='Urban'):
      df.at[index,'x'] = '3'
   elif ( df.at[index,'prop_area'] =='Semiurban'):
      df.at[index,'x'] = '4'
   elif ( df.at[index,'prop_area'] =='Someothertype'):
      df.at[index,'x'] = '5'
   else:
       continue
```